# Angular2's component's styles are not inherited in the encapsulated child component

Tags: angular

I am writing two components - `ComponentA` and `ComponentB`, where `ComponentA` encapsulates `ComponentB`. Both of them have a `p` tag. In my `ComponentA`, I am writing styles: `p { color:red }` inside my `@Component` decorator. The `ComponentA`'s `p` is changed to red but `ComponentB`'s color remains black.

I think it's a bug which needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Style encapsulation (preventing style from bleeding into or out of components) is a main feature of Angular components.

There are different options to achieve what you want

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'component-b',
  styles: [`
    p { color: red; }
  `]
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

or you can change the CSS selector to cross component boundaries with the recently introduced (Angular2 only) shadow piercing CSS combinator `>>>`

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'component-b',
  styles: [`
    :host ::ng-deep p { color: red; }
  `]
  ...
})
```

The 2nd approach works with the default encapsulation (`ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`).
You can't use `::ng-deep` (`>>>`) with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`.
Support for `>>>` (or the equivalent `/deep/`) was removed from Chrome and never really supported in other browsers.

**hint**:
<strike>`/deep/` seems to work better with SASS than `>>>`</strike>
SASS introduced `::ng-deep` a while back to support this Angular feature (when support for `/deep/` was removed from SASS)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have just started angular2. Can you give me little more idea about "encapsulation: ViewEncpasulation.None" and other options?

Comment: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewEncapsulation-enum.html

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-say-hello-world-to-angular-2?series=angular-2-fundamentals also have a video regarding ViewEncpasulation

Comment: Isn't there an error ? you are re-defining the red color into component-b and not component-a

Comment: Shadow piercing support [was removed](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120) from all browsers so I would suggest avoiding the second approach. Thanks to [Douglas Henrique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738902/angular2s-components-styles-are-not-inherited-in-the-encapsulated-child-compon/52023624#comment92512285_52023624) for the source

Comment: @JonathanGinn the 2nd approach is with
  `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (default) and therefore not dependent on browser support. If you avoid it you deprive yourself of an important feature that has no alternative. The new slotted in ...
  `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` isn't fully supported in all browsers yet. I'll update my question because since a while `::ng-deep` should be used because that is also supported in SASS (was added especially for Angular)

Comment: Note: (deprecated) /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep. Styles Between Components in Angular 2+ https://alligator.io/angular/styles-between-components-angular/

Comment: I wondered why it doesn't mention https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the accepted answer: **this is not a bug**.

That said, here are two alternatives to inheriting parent styles:

### @Component({ styleUrls })

Adding the parent component style sheet to the list of styleUrls:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../parent.component.css', './child.component.css']
//             ^^ Going up
})

export class AppChildComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

---

### Preprocessor Imports (SCSS, SASS, LESS)

You can also import parent styles using preprocessors. You'll just need to adjust your project settings to use them:

```css
@import "../parent.component.sass"
// .app-parent-component
//   border: 1px solid red

.app-child-component
  border: 1px solid blue
```

---

### Compiled Output

Both will generate the classes with the right scope so you'll have effectively inherited the parent styles.

```css
/* Compiled CSS */
.app-parent-component[_ngcontent-c1=""] {
  border: 1px solid red; }

/* Redeclares parent styles but with the child's scope */
.app-parent-component[_ngcontent-c2=""] {
  border: 1px solid red; }
.app-child-component[_ngcontent-c2=""] {
  border: 1px solid blue; }
```

Comment: you answer seems thorough, but you should address the question's misconceptions and sentiment/thinking regarding the observation being a bug. i,e. is Angular2's component styles not inheriting because of a bug?

Comment: @BrettCaswell Thank-you for reminding me; I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Best answer as shadow piercing support [was removed](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120) from all browsers.

Comment: As mentined in my answer. That shadow piercing support was removed from browsers (or never supported) is irrelevant to Angular because `::ng-deep`, (`>>>`, `/deep/`) never depended on browser support. They are **emulated** by Angular.

Answer (score 7):

It is not a bug.

> Component styles normally apply only to the HTML in the component's own template -- [reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors)

If you want styles that you define in a parent component to affect ancestor components, I would use the use the `/deep/` selector (which has the alias `>>>` as Günter used in his answer) in the parent component, which will force the style down through all ancestor components.
Note that this will apply the style to all view children as well as content children.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-a',
  styles: [`/deep/ p { color: red; }`]
})
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gf9iiPAIuYKfipJCcqxJ?p=preview)</kbd>

See also the [Special Selectors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors) section in the Component Styles dev guide.