# How do I get my Angular 6 components to inherit it's extended component's styles?

Tags: angular, typescript

I basically want to extend a component and inherit it's styles, but the `app-another` component is not inheriting the `base-component.css`.

#### base.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  templateUrl: './base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base.component.css']
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

#### another.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseComponent } from './base/base.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-another',
  templateUrl: './another.component.html'
})
export class AnotherComponent extends BaseComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Am I doing something stupid?

Or is this not supported yet?

It would be cool to be able to add it in the AnotherComponent style array:

```
styleUrls: BaseComponent.styleUrls.concat(["./another.component.css"])
```

## This is basically what i want to achieve:

```
styleUrls: ['./base/base.component.css', "./another.component.scss"]
```

but since base is actually in it's own Angular library in another Node module, it's not accessible like this.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Did the answers from this question not work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738902/angular2s-components-styles-are-not-inherited-in-the-encapsulated-child-compon

Comment: Unfortunately not because it's not a child component. It's an extended component . I don't think the issue is to do with encapsulation.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should consider structuring your app in a better way. I do not understand why you want to inherit the styles from another component. Each component has its own private styles to avoid global styles and no inheritance. If you want you can promote those specific styles to a higher level, like putting them in styles.scss so they can be shared across your app. That is my opinion.

Also, you can check out this link https://alligator.io/angular/styles-between-components-angular/ where you can see special pseudo-elements that could work for you. Maybe parent > child way to structure it. I've never done something like this. But here you have my thoughts on this topic. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The BaseComponent lives in a custom Angular library and the AnotherComponent lives in the main app so promoting them to a higher css file isn't possible. If you extend a component, you would probably want the option of inheriting the template and/or the styles. Surely I'm not the first to want to do this haha.